# Import project from Github to androidstudio (Gradle)

Tags: android, git, android-studio

My team has a repository in bitbucket which I need to clone and use in my system. I tried VCS > checkout from Version control > Git then gave the repo url, path specifying the directory where the project has to be cloned and the project directory name.

The cloning went well and I can find the project dir in the filesystem. After that is asking some permission regarding gradle and asking for inputs regarding where the gradle is present. I selected the gradle in my android-studio and it accepted it. When I click ok it is throwing the following error.

**The screenshot of gradle input:**
[image: The screenshot of gradle input]

**The screenshot of error:**
[image: The screenshot of error]

Then I went to my SDK manager and installed all the android versions from 2.3 to 6.0 . Still the error persists.

Comment: this is build tool not SDK version

Comment: oh.. so what can i do to overcome my error ? @mdtuyen

Comment: I don't use android studio for ubuntu, but with android studio for Mac or Window you can select to install build tool automatic. With your case you can refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

File->New->Project from version control->Git:
Clone repository: Your bitbucket url

https://username@bitbucket.org/team/projectname.git

EDIT:
Install sdk 23:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: I m trying it now.. Just a min

Comment: I opened the cloned project in a new window.. then it said   Unlinked Gradle project?
Import Gradle project, this will also enable Gradle Tool Window. Don't want to see the message for the project again: press here. Clicking it again is taking me to the import gradle popup

Comment: How to install apk 23 and g20 said to instal sdk 23 .. what s the difference? @pcg26

Comment: sorry g20 is on the true, my bad, sdk 23 xD

Comment: Thank you very much  @pcg26 .. the sdk update worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer found:

Steps to import the repo
https://bitbucket.org/variabletech/libnode-android-public/wiki/Project%20Setup%20(Android%20Studio)

Steps to update sdk 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/help/sdk-manager.html